Why do my line graph dashed grid lines disappear when I hover over graph point data?
My Chart.js line graph dashed border grid line vanishes for few few seconds when I hover over graph point data. This also happens when I activate and deactivate datasets using the "This Month" and "Last Month" toggles.
Also, my data line appears to be backwards of those grid lines. The grid lines are supposed to be backward of the data line.
I tried increasing the z index for data lines, but it still shows the data line backward of the grid line.
Also, regarding the grid line disappearing concerns, I tried plain grid lines, which worked, but I wanted to use dashed border grid lines.
I want those grid lines to be backward of the data line, and when I hover over a graph point, it should stay fixed rather than disappear for a few seconds. Also, when I activate and deactivate a data line using the toggle option, the grid line should not vanish at all.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Line graph</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .market-activity-chart-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .market-activity-chart-container canvas {
            background: #ffffff; 
            width: 100%; 
            max-width: 700px;
            height: 100%; 
        }

        .market-this-months,
        .market-last-months {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 8px;
            cursor: pointer;
            opacity: 0.5;
            transition: opacity 0.3s; 
        }

        .market-this-months.active,
        .market-last-months.active {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .market-months-flex {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            gap: 16px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-5">
            <div class="dashboard-card">
                <div class="market-activity-chart-container">
                    <canvas id="marketActivityChart"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="market-months-flex">
                    <div class="market-this-months active" id="toggleThisMonth">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none">
                            <circle cx="6" cy="6" r="4.5" fill="white" stroke="#5159A7" stroke-width="3"/>
                        </svg>
                        <span>This Month</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="market-last-months" id="toggleLastMonth">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none">
                            <circle cx="6" cy="6" r="4.5" fill="white" stroke="#F8C140" stroke-width="3"/>
                        </svg>
                        <span>Last Month</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script>
        const ctxMarketActivity = document.getElementById('marketActivityChart').getContext('2d');

        const marketActivityData = {
            labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'This Month',
                    data: [5500, 2800, 3800, 3900, 7800, 5800, 7600, 4000],
                    borderColor: '#4F45B6',
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    fill: false,
                    tension: 0,
                    pointRadius: 0, 
                    pointHoverRadius: 5, 
                    order: 2,
                },
                {
                    label: 'Last Month',
                    data: [3800, 2700, 2800, 1400, 6000, 5500, 5600, 3800],
                    borderColor: '#F8C140',
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    fill: false,
                    tension: 0,
                    pointRadius: 0, 
                    pointHoverRadius: 5, 
                    order: 2,
                }
            ]
        };

        const marketActivityChart = new Chart(ctxMarketActivity, {
            type: 'line',
            data: marketActivityData,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: false,
                        min: 1000,
                        max: 10000,
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 2000,
                            callback: function(value) {
                                return value >= 1000 ? value / 1000 + 'k' : value;
                            },
                            font: {
                                family: 'Gilroy-Medium',
                                size: 18,
                                style: 'normal',
                                weight: '400'
                            },
                            color: '#101839',
                            lineHeight: 34,
                            textTransform: 'capitalize',
                            opacity: 0.4,
                            padding: 16
                        },
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        border: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    },
                    x: {
                        ticks: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: false, 
                        external: function(context) {
                            const { chart, tooltip } = context;
                            const tooltipEl = document.querySelector('.chartjs-tooltip') || document.createElement('div');

                            if (!document.querySelector('.chartjs-tooltip')) {
                                tooltipEl.classList.add('chartjs-tooltip');
                                tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
                                tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                                tooltipEl.style.color = '#fff';
                                tooltipEl.style.padding = '10px 28px'; 
                                tooltipEl.style.borderRadius = '10px';
                                tooltipEl.style.fontSize = '20px';
                                tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = 'Arial, sans-serif';
                                tooltipEl.style.zIndex = 1000; 
                                document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
                            }

                            if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
                                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                                return;
                            }

                            // Determine tooltip background color based on dataset
                            const datasetIndex = tooltip.dataPoints[0].datasetIndex;
                            tooltipEl.style.backgroundColor = datasetIndex === 1 ? '#F8C140' : '#5159A7';

                            // Tooltip content
                            const tooltipData = tooltip.dataPoints.map(dp => `<div>${dp.formattedValue}</div>`).join('');
                            tooltipEl.innerHTML = tooltipData;

                            // Tooltip position
                            const position = chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                            tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
                            tooltipEl.style.left = `${position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltip.caretX}px`;
                            tooltipEl.style.top = `${position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltip.caretY}px`;
                        }
                    }
                },
                animation: {
                    onComplete: function() {
                        const chartArea = marketActivityChart.chartArea;
                        const yScale = marketActivityChart.scales.y;
                        const ctx = marketActivityChart.ctx;

                        const yLabels = yScale.ticks.map(tick => tick.value);

                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.strokeStyle = '#A098AE';
                        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
                        ctx.setLineDash([6, 6]);

                        yLabels.forEach(label => {
                            const yPos = yScale.getPixelForValue(label);
                            ctx.beginPath();
                            ctx.moveTo(chartArea.left, yPos);
                            ctx.lineTo(chartArea.right, yPos);
                            ctx.stroke();
                        });

                        ctx.restore();
                    }
                },
                elements: {
                    point: {
                        radius: function(context) {
                            return context.active ? 5 : 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        function updateToggleStates() {
            const thisMonthButton = document.querySelector('.market-this-months');
            const lastMonthButton = document.querySelector('.market-last-months');
            
            // Check dataset visibility and update classes
            if (marketActivityChart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden) {
                thisMonthButton.classList.add('inactive');
                thisMonthButton.classList.remove('active');
            } else {
                thisMonthButton.classList.add('active');
                thisMonthButton.classList.remove('inactive');
            }

            if (marketActivityChart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden) {
                lastMonthButton.classList.add('inactive');
                lastMonthButton.classList.remove('active');
            } else {
                lastMonthButton.classList.add('active');
                lastMonthButton.classList.remove('inactive');
            }
        }

        updateToggleStates();

        // Toggle visibility 
        document.querySelector('.market-this-months').addEventListener('click', function() {
            const dataset = marketActivityChart.getDatasetMeta(0);
            dataset.hidden = !dataset.hidden;
            marketActivityChart.update();

            updateToggleStates();
        });

        document.querySelector('.market-last-months').addEventListener('click', function() {
            const dataset = marketActivityChart.getDatasetMeta(1);
            dataset.hidden = !dataset.hidden;
            marketActivityChart.update();
            updateToggleStates();
        });
       
    </script>
</body>
</html>


All the issues you describe are the result of your choice to do your custom line drawing in the animation onComplete callback. The lines will not be visible during the time the animation runs and will be drawn on top of the datasets. Move that code in a custom plugin's beforeDraw or  beforeDatasetsDraw handlers to have then displayed during the animation also, and under the datasets, e.g., fiddle. Also, I'm not sure why you don't use standard chart.js grid for those lines.
